# How to align view in react native in loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Here is my React Native component code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default class AnatomyExample extends Component {
  render() {
    let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
        {data.map(this.renderView)}
      </View>


    );
  }

  renderView(d){
    return (
     <View style={styles.child}>
      <Text>{d}</Text>
       </View>
      )
  }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  },
  child: {
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'blue',
    width:150,
    height:150,

  }
});
```

I want to make component output look like this image. 
[image]

How to float View side by side. `float:left;` would work in html css but not sure how to make it in react native.

Comment: React-Native uses flexbox so floating does not work - you have to add flex-wrap: wrap to your container and give the children a width e.g. 100px.

Comment: @davidbucka can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the styles like this, if you want *4 elements in a row* else you can specify *custom width*

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')
main: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  },
  child: {
    margin: 5,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'blue',
    width: width / 4 - 12, // ... DeviceWidth / 4 - (marginLeft + marginRight + borderLeft + borderRight)
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'gray'

  }
```

Comment: Thank you Pratish